Can I publish a thesis here?
Can I publish a thesis here? Is it possible to share Doctorate's thesis about the education through the acts in early stage of a children
Also I was wondering about the thesis language should it be only English or it's ok from diffrent languages.

Not at all. This is main meta, for issues relating to the StackExchange Q&A network as a whole. There is no site on the network suited to publishing academic papers, you need to seek a journal of one of the usual outlets. You could however take a look at our [academia.se] site, and using the search facility get advice on how to do that. If you decide to post a question there, be sure to take their tour, and refer to the help centre before you post. Our [psychology.se] site may offer relevant information too.

Just a thought, our [writing.se] site may be able to offer something, A search there reveals a number of questions with both tags [publishing] and [academic writing].

Not on this very site, Meta Stack Exchange; this is a site to discuss the network itself.
All Stack Exchange sites are question and answer sites. If you can formulate your thesis as a self-answered question, which is on-topic for the target site (example), while keeping in mind the 30k character limit for posts, it might work. But why would you? There are many other sites on the Internet for publishing theses - why choose one that isn't purposed for it? One doesn't publish theses as Wikipedia articles either.

In fairness, publishing your thesis as a Wikipedia article is explicitly against the rules.

Tnere's probably a ban on original research, yeah.

Oh, hey. You can actually publish your thesis on Wikiversity (another Wikimedia Foundation site).
